# How to fix blurry downscaled images in browsers

Tags: html, css, image, image-processing

I have this problem where images with text on them looks very blurry on my website, if the browsers downscale them, when they extend their parents width. It seems to be a problem in all browsers.

I have tried the `image-rendering` css which doesn't work:

```
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: pls explain more with example

Comment: An example would be good. But I'll already say this: if you can, don't use images with text in them. Instead, make use of the advantages of HTML and CSS: overlay images with actual text. This way, the text will stay crisp.

Comment: Also know that up- or downscaling of images, will always produce undesired effects. Sometimes more, sometimes less, depending on the image and the amount of scaling. But you'll always have some amount of loss in quality. Text in images is especially prone to that, hence why I'd use images without text.